# Why did the Google Drive iOS API stop running in my app?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I've figured out the answer to this, but thought I'd post the question and the answer since it took me quite a while to figure it out.

I had been using the Google Drive iOS/Objective C API (see https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart) in my app for some time. And all was going fine. In the last few days I was trying to extend my use of it, and in my new use, as part of what I was doing, I wanted the Google API access to occur in the background, and not hold up the UI. So, I dispatched the call to the Google API like this:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            // Call Google Drive
        });
```

The results were mixed. I was getting partial results. Seemingly, it would work until I relaunched my app, and then it would stop. Despite the fact I still had the user authorization credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Making a long debugging process short (I tried every last thing that I'd changed), I finally narrowed this down to a threading problem. Running the Google API call on the main thread (which I'd been doing in my original usage of the Google API), things started working. And I find in the Google docs:

> Typically, applications will execute queries on the main thread, and
>   the query completion handler will be called back on the main thread.
>
> Alternatively, an application can execute a query on a background
>   thread and will be called back on that same background thread, though
>   the application must run an NSRunLoop on that thread for the callbacks
>   to occur.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction

And the following text is important too:

> Beginning with iOS 6 and Mac OS X 10.7, a query may be executed on
>   either the main thread or a background thread, and be called back on
>   either the main thread or a background thread. To have callbacks occur
>   on a different thread than the query was executed on, specify an
>   NSOperationQueue (not a dispatch queue) for the service object's
>   delegateQueue property.
>
> For example, queries made from any thread can be called back on the
>   main thread by using the main queue:
>
> service.delegateQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]; Queries made
>   from any thread can be called back on a background thread by providing
>   a background queue, as in this example:
>
> service.delegateQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; When a
>   delegate queue is specified, there is no requirement for a run loop to
>   be running on the thread that executes the query.